# EF Find() The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have a problem with EF , when I am trying to get some model data by Id like in those example :

```
Company company = context.Companies.Find(id);
```

EF throw me to this Exception:
The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.
The problem that is earlier it worked , BUT now without any reason a lot of(not all) Find() functions shows it.

Controller:

```
var modelEmpl = (RegisterEmployeeView)model;
                        user.Employee = modelEmpl.Employee;
                        user.Avatar = Galary.Avatar(file, "Avatar", context);
                        result = UserManager.Create(user, modelEmpl.Password);
                        var prof = (Profesion)context.Profesions.Find(modelEmpl.Profesion.Id);
                        user.Employee.Profesion = prof;
                        CreatingEmployee(user);


...

 private void CreatingEmployee(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            Company comp = context.Companies.Find(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
            Employee empl = context.Employees.Find(user.Id);
            //empl.Profesion = user.Employe.Profesion;
            empl.Family = new Family() {SalaryAcsess = false , GalleryAcsess = false , WeatherAcsess = false , LocationAcsess = false};
            comp.Employees.Add(empl);
            context.Entry(comp).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Model(I will send only Company model , but it throwing exception with all models):

```
public class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>();
        }
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

EF Version:6.0.0.0 , Runtime Version : v4.0.30319

**UPDATE:**
One more "simptom":  when I am calling Find() before UserManager.Create(user, modelEmpl.Password) it's working

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Find instead of something like FirstOrDefault?

Comment: No , I just wanna know why does it happens for personal experience.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Can you post more of your code? It's hard to know just from that where the problem could be. I've had that message pop up for seemingly completely unrelated reasons in the past...

Comment: Can you post the Company class definition?

Comment: It seems, you want to change company Id which you didn't post in your question.

Comment: With EF6, it's impossible that the `Find` method throws this error (ef-core is more buggy, but not likely to show this error either). It must be something else in your code.